# The right way to stop recyclerview from recycling and rebinding viewholders

Tags: android

I have a recycler view which I want to stop it from recycling and rebinding view holders. I can achieve this goal by putting the recycler view inside a nested scroll view but I think it's not the right way.

I want to know if there is a better way to this or not?

Comment: Why is it you want a RecyclerView to stop recycling? The whole point of using one is recycling. To rebind view holders with new data, you pass the new data into the recyclerview's adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() on it.

Comment: Because I have a nested recycler view inside some view types (something like play store home activity) and its heavy to even rebind them. Also the main recycler view dosnt contain much items (not more than 10) so its not heavy to stop recycling them. I have better performance when I put the recycler view inside of a nested scroll view

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use listview then with arrayadapter its deprecated now but doesnt recycles the list. But use it if there are less items in the list that wont take much heap memory or else it will freeze the screen.